# Query from two tables where match could be in any table from passed data

Tags: php, sql, database

I am having a mail system where students can receive a message from students as well as staffs and vice versa. However, staffs table differs from students tables.

#### Pseudo:

I want to get `name` and `picture` where `message_by` could either be from `staffs table` or `students table`

**message_by** could either be student id or staff id.

I tried this and I know it's wrong but someway somehow it works for the students and messes up when it finds a staff in the message_by column

```
<?php

 $message_by = $irow['message_by'];

 $fql = "SELECT DISTINCT s.first_name as first_name, 
     s.other_names as other_names, s.avatar as avatar
     FROM lm_students s, lm_staff c WHERE s.index_number = ? OR c.staff_id = ? ";  

 $fstmt = $db->prepare($fql);
 $fstmt->bind_param('ss',$message_by,$message_by);
 $fstmt->execute();
      
      $fstmt->store_result();
      $fstmt->bind_result($first_name,$other_names,$s_avatar);
      $fstmt->fetch();

?>
```

I know I'm not using the `c.staff_id` because I don't know how to make it work for both.

Hoping everyone could help. Thanks

Comment: Keep all users in a single table

Comment: Is that the only solution ‍♂️? As the project is more than halfway through which could cause a whole lot mess to clean up if merged

Comment: @WanPeninsula Better to do it now than when live. You could use a `union` but that is messy... and you're going to hate this schema when it is live and you have to work with a large amount of the data.

Comment: Ohk thanks very much. Have made arrangements for now but in the meantime, the answer I added works fine.

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

So this query works for now

```
<?php 

 $fql = "SELECT DISTINCT first_name,other_names,avatar FROM lm_students WHERE index_number = ? UNION SELECT first_name,other_names,avatar FROM lm_staff WHERE  staff_id = ?";
?>
```

Hope someone finds it useful but a better approach would be appreciated anytime